# Simplifying logarithmic equations

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, logarithms, systems-of-equations, substitution

$$(\log x) ^2 (\log y + \log z) =1$$

$$(\log y) ^2 (\log x + \log z) =2$$

$$(\log z) ^2 (\log y + \log x) =5$$

Find $\log x  \cdot  \log y \cdot \log z$ ?

It is fairly obvious that the problem could have several answers.

A difficult method would be to solve three equations in three variables and calculating the product.

But how can I make use of certain logarithm properties to ease the search of the solution?

Comment: Please tell aus more about this problem. Where did it come from? Maybe you made some mistakes by manipulating the equations.  It is no problem about logarithm. Substitute log x by u, log y by v, and log z by w and the logarithm disappears without any impact to the problems.

Comment: It is a homework problem.

Comment: I have checked the equations.

Comment: Was it actually posed  in this way?

Comment: It was (log x)^[log y]^log z to be found out.

Comment: That is even more strange. Is this ((log x)^(log y))^(log z) or (log x) ^((log y)^(log z))?

Comment: The First one .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $\log{x}=a$, $\log{y}=b$ and $\log{z}=c$.

Hence, $a^2b^2c^2(a+b)(a+c)(b+c)=10$ and $\sum\limits_{cyc}(a^2b+a^2c)=8$.

Thus, $a^2b^2c^2(8+2abc)=10$, which gives 
$$(abc-1)(a^2b^2c^2+5abc+5)=0$$

Comment: How does the cyclic sigma work ?

Comment: @Anmol Agarwal  $\sum\limits_{cyc}a^2(b+c)=a^2(b+c)+b^2(c+a)+c^2(a+b)$

Comment: How did you obtain {   }=10 ?

Comment: @Anmol Agarwal $10=1\cdot2\cdot5$

Comment: @Anmol Agarwal I can show that all these three values are valid, but it's very ugly work.

Answer (score 0):

Setting $$\log(x)=a,\log(y)=b,\log(z)=c$$ then we have to solve

\begin{align}a^2(b+c)&=1\\
b^2(c+a)&=2\\
c^2(a+b)&=5\end{align}

Eliminating $b,c$ from the system then we get, for $a$

$$13a^3-101a^6+9a^9+2=0$$

Can you solve this?

Comment: Something is odd. If by eliminating $b,c$ you get such equation, by cyclic symmetry we have that $a^3,b^3,c^3$ are roots of the polynomial $p(x)=9x^3-101x^2+13x-2$. In such a case $a^3 b^3 c^2 = \frac{2}{9}$ by Vieta's theorem, but Micheal's answer clearly shows that $abc=1$.

Comment: i think it is $$13a^3-101a^6+9a^9+2=0$$

Comment: All right, if that happens then $a^3$ is a root of $p(x)=9x^3-101x^2+13x+2$. The same happens for $b$ and $c$, so $a^3 b^3 c^3=-\frac{2}{9}$ by Vieta's theorem and something's still odd.